# Executing commands in normal mode at startup

Tags: vim

I need to execute these commands at startup:

```
Ctrl+w J
Ctrl+w k
Ctrl+w l
Ctrl+w L
```

in vim to place windows in special way. What should I put in .vimrc? I tried this:

```
execute "normal \<C-W> J"
execute "normal \<C-W> k"
execute "normal \<C-W> l"
execute "normal \<C-W> L"
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space that you put between the closing angle bracket and the letter means that you're telling Vim to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>spacebar</kbd> then some normal mode command that isn't a window command.  Remove the spaces and you'll be good.

The Ctrl-W commands can also be named `:wincmd` so you could also replace all of the execute/normal shenanigans like this:

```
wincmd J
wincmd k
wincmd l
wincmd L
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you want to organize a default workspace. If I'm right, you need to read `:help :mksession`.

Your `~/.vimrc` is read before any window is created so putting window-related commands in it doesn't really make much sense.